# Covering S2 with great circles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, set-theory

Let $S_2$ be the unit 2-dimensional sphere. Is there a way to cover it with great circles such that each point on $S_2$ has 1 or 2 great circles that go through it?

Comment: If we assume the axiom of choice then it should be possible to do it by
well-ordering $S_2 / \{ \pm1 \}$ so that every initial segment has
cardinality less than $c$, and using transfinite induction:
if $p$ is the first pair that has not been covered then there's a continuum of
great circles through $p$, and $\#\{q: q \prec p\}^2 < c$ previous intersections
to avoid, so we can choose a great circle that creates no triple intersection.
Hopefully a more honest construction is possible!

Comment: The tag (geometry) is deprecated on MathOverflow and should not be used - see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). Perhaps there are some other suitable tags? (Maybe [tag:mg.metric-geometry]?)

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies Very much appreciated your reply. As I'm not familiar with this, may I ask a dumb and elementary question: why every initial segment of this well-ordered set $S_2/\{\pm 1\}$ has cardinality less than $c$, despite that the whole set has cardinality $c$?

Comment: @Martin Sleziak  Thanks for the information on tags. I'm not quite sure about what tags are suitable for this question. Please feel free to add it if you have a good choice in mind.

Comment: @Y.X You're welcome.  The key is that there's a *first* ordinal, say $\Pi$,
such that the corresponding set of ordinals $\alpha < \Pi$ has cardinality $c$.
(Under the continuum hypothesis, $\Pi$ is the first uncountable ordinal,
which is called $\omega_1$ or $\Omega$ according to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal .)  
Now choose an arbitrary bijection from the set of such $\alpha$ to 
$S_2 / \{ \pm 1 \}$, and use that bijection to define the ordering $\prec$
on $S_2 / \{ \pm 1 \}$.

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies I see. Thank you again!